# React-Redux, how to change state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i have such problem: I'm making To-Do-List, and now I want to make EditMode for my tasks. But when I try to do it, it returns string not an array, and that's why I have 3 errors (map,some,filter = is not a function). So I don't know how to change state(task) and return changed array.

Some details: I'm using connect to get props.

**Component's code**

```
class Item extends React.Component {
    state = {
        statusChange: false,
        task: ''
    }

    activeStatusChange = () => {
        this.setState( {
            statusChange: true
           }
       );        
    }

    deActivateStatusChange = () => {
        this.setState( {
            statusChange: false
           }
       );      
       this.props.editTask(this.state.task)
    }

    onStatusChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            task: e.currentTarget.value
        })
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <div className={s.item}>
            <span onClick={this.props.editStatus} className={s.statusTask}>
                {this.props.status  ? <img src="https://img.icons8.com/doodle/48/000000/checkmark.png"/> 
                                    : <img src="https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/red-circle-emoji.png"/>}
            </span>

            { this.state.statusChange 
                ? <input onChange={this.onStatusChange} autoFocus={true} onBlur={this.deActivateStatusChange} value={this.state.task} /> 
                : <span  className={this.props.status === true ? s.task : s.taskFalse} onClick={this.activeStatusChange}> {this.props.task} </span>}

            <span onClick={this.props.deleteTask} className={s.close}><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/close-window.png"/></span>

        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Item;
```

**Reducer's code**

```
import React from 'react'
import shortid from 'shortid';

const ADD_TASK = 'ADD_TASK'
const EDIT_STATUS = 'EDIT_STATUS'
const TASK_DELETE = 'TASK_DELETE'
const REMOVE_ALL_DONE = 'REMOVE_ALL_DONE'
const REMOVE_ALL_TASKS = 'REMOVE_ALL_TASKS'
const EDIT_TASK = 'EDIT_TASK'

const initialState = {
    tasks: []
};



const mainReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ADD_TASK: {
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: [{
                    id: shortid.generate(),
                    task: action.task,
                    status: false
                }, ...state.tasks]
            }
        }

        case EDIT_STATUS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: state.tasks.map(task => task.id === action.id ? {...task, status: !task.status} : task)
            }
        }

        case TASK_DELETE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: state.tasks.filter(t => t.id !== action.id)
            }
        }

        case REMOVE_ALL_DONE: {
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: state.tasks.filter(t => !t.status)
            }
        }

        case REMOVE_ALL_TASKS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: []
            }
        }

        case EDIT_TASK: {
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: action.task
            }
        }

    default:
        return state
    }
}


export const addTask = task => ({type: 'ADD_TASK', task});
export const editStatus = id => ({type: 'EDIT_STATUS', id})
export const deleteTask = id => ({type: 'TASK_DELETE', id})
export const removeAllDone = () => ({type:'REMOVE_ALL_DONE'})
export const removeAllTasks = () => ({type: 'REMOVE_ALL_TASKS'})
export const editTask = task => ({type: 'EDIT_TASK', task})


export default mainReducer;
```

Comment: in your example you didn't wrap ```Item``` component to ```connect```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a container that uses the methods mapDispatchToProps so you can use your actions in the component.

```
https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch
```

So lets do it. Just create a file that will be your container for that component and put the code like this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import Item from 'wherever your component is';
import { addTask } from 'wherever your action is';


const mapStateToProps = ({  }) => ({
    // Here you can pass the redu state to your component
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  ...bindActionCreators({
      // Here you pass the action to your component
      addTask
  }, dispatch)
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Item);
```

Then when you want to use the Item component import it from the container and it will receive in props both the action and the state that you are passing from the container file.

In you Item component you can use the action like this:

```
// ITem component
render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.props.addTask} />
    )
}
```

If any doubt just let me know!

Comment: This is my architecture of ToDoList:
(setItem,SetItemContainer - this component recieves props) then in SetItem component i have ListTasks component, and there is Item component. Props which recieve SetItem component I give to ListTasks and then to Item. Should I make one more container components?

Comment: You need a container for the parent component in order tl receive the props, then just pass them to the other components as regular props.

Comment: But this component get props from component above which has container component. And all props what I need - i got them.

Comment: I think problem whith reducer, because it returns sring but not array

Comment: You need to pass the state with mapStateToProps in the reducer